# Best way to rig poly hair?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I have made a model of which I plan to use automatic weights for the body, and parent objects that dont need to move dynamically like the eyes, teeth and such to the armature by selecting the object, the the right and CTRL + P then parenting to a specific bone.

However I have poly modeled the hair, and was wondering if using separate, individual armatures for each group of hair would be smart? And if these hair armatures could be attached to a completely separate armature? How would you go about doing this?

Please see below for screenshots :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello why would you use different armatures? Maybe create a chain of bone for each group of hair? Also maybe consider a bit of physic like cloth or maybe an addon like BoneDynamic or Wiggle Bones that fake physics?

Comment: Hello, wiggle bone may work, does that require much weight painting as the way the hair is made it would be tough to manually weight paint them?

Comment: If the hair armatures and hair objects are separate armatures and objects, try a parent With Automatic Weights, then you'll join to the main armature and body. Also try BoneDynamic, it may be simpler to use.

Comment: If you join several armatures, make sure that they don't have the same bones name before joining

Comment: This is all very useful! Thanks! :)